# Exercise on a holomorphic $f$ on a strip satisfying $|f(z)|\leq A(1+|z|)^\eta$

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the following problem:

> If $f$ is a holomorphic function on the strip $S=\{z=x+iy:-1<y<1,x\in{\Bbb R}\}$ with
>   $$
> |f(z)|\leq A(1+|z|)^{\eta} \tag{1}
> $$
>   for all $z\in S$, where $\eta$ is a fixed real number, show that for each integer $n\geq 0$ there exists $A_n\geq 0$ so that
>   $$
> |f^{(n)}(x)|\leq A_n(1+|x|)^{\eta}\tag{2}
> $$
>   for all $x\in{\Bbb R}$.

Let $C_R=\{z\in{\Bbb C}:|z|=R\}$. Then for every $0<R<1$, by Cauchy inequality, we have
$$
|f^{(n)}(x)|\leq\frac{n!}{R^n}\|f\|_{x+C_R}\leq \frac{n!}{R^n}A(1+|x|+R)^\eta\tag{3}
$$
where $x+C_R=\{x+z:z\in C_R\}$ and $\|f\|_{x+C_R}=\sup\{f(z):z\in x+C_R\}$. But I don't see how I can get rid of the $R$ here. Any help?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but my hunch is you want to integrate over rectangles with height $2 - \epsilon$ and width $2R$ "centered" at $x$, and send $R \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: @uncookedfalcon A stretched-out rectangle does not offer any advantage over, say, a square of the same height. Indeed, about half of the integral over the square comes from its horizontal sides, and the rectangle contains those too.

Comment: Are you tacitly assuming that $\eta$ is non-negative?

Comment: @CuriousKid7: no, $\eta$ is some fixed real number.

Comment: But does the second inequality in (3) hold when $\eta <0$?

Comment: @Jack what is $||f||_{x+C_R}$ ? Is it a circle $C_R$ centered at x? I din't understand why |x| is added to the right of the equation in $A(1+|x|+R)^\eta$?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 In case that $\eta<0$, just fix $R=1/2$ and bound it from above by $n!2^n(|x|+1/2)^\eta\leq n!4^n(|x|+1)^\eta$ when $|x|>1$. Also, note that $f^{(n)}(x)$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$, so it is naturally bounded. Putting these together we show that such an $A_n$ exists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just fix $R=1/2$, estimate $3/2+|x| \le 3/2(1+|x|)$, and include $(3/2)^\eta$ in your $A_n$.

Comment: A tighter bound would be to keep R a variable, include $(1+R)^\eta$ in your $A_n$, and then let $R\to 1$. Not that it matters for this problem in isolation